# optimized single mysql query needed

Tags: mysql, sql

I`d like to find out how to build a single mysql query that retrieves * for all TESTIDs on the db. So instead of running a for loop for each unique TESTID generating multiple db calls like the ones below,  I can simply run one query.

```
select * from test_results where TESTERID='3' and TESTID='5'
select * from test_results where TESTERID='3' and TESTID='9'
select * from test_results where TESTERID='3' and TESTID='10'
select * from test_results where TESTERID='3' and TESTID='12'
select * from test_results where TESTERID='3' and TESTID='15'
select * from test_results where TESTERID='3' and TESTID='4'
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: You said for all TESTID on the db? So just don't include the last "and" clause: select * from test_results where TESTERID='3'

Answer (score 4):

you can remove single quotes if the datatype of the columns are numeric (*number*), otherwise wrap it if not.

```
SELECT *
FROM   test_results 
WHERE  testerID = 3 AND
       testID IN (5,9,10,12,15,4)
```

Comment: what do you mean by *new testids as they get generated*? do you want to retrieve all records where `testerID = 3`? the you can directly do this, `SELECT *
FROM   test_results 
WHERE  testerID = 3`

Answer (score 3):

I would assume you're looking for this?

```
SELECT *
FROM test_results
WHERE
    TESTERID = '3'
    AND TESTID IN ('5', '9', '10', '12', '15', '4')
```

If you are using a numeric type of field you should probably use this instead btw:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_results
WHERE
    TESTERID = 3
    AND TESTID IN (5, 9, 10, 12, 15, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all records from testerid='3'

```
select * from test_results where TESTERID='3'
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, I came up with the following working solution:

```
SELECT * FROM test_results WHERE testerID = 3 AND testID IN (select TESTID from test_results)
```

Comment: As a lot of people have already pointed out, why do you need to check TestID at all? the second part of your where clause `AND testID IN (Select TESTID from test_results)` is essentially saying `AND 1 = 1`. It's always going to be true

Comment: you are absolutely right Greg. Time to get some rest and rethink the problem. thanks.